# Find spanning tree that specific v has k degrees

Tags: algorithm, depth-first-search

can someone explain for me how to solve it i know that we should use DFS but i cant understand what we do after that.

```
input : undirected graph G and specific v that belong to the G
output : spanning tree that v has k degree
```

Comment: is it the statement of the exercise you don't understand or how to solve it ?

Comment: no i have exam today and this question from old exam that i cant read what the answer because the hand writing is sucks, i know you have to run dfs and if d(v) > k you need to replace tree edge with back edge or something like that i could not fully understand what written :(.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will suggest the following way.
Here I assume G is connected.
First remove v from the graph, find spanning tree for each of the remaining component.

Now you may have a single spanning tree or a forest depending on the graph, you can add back v and use the edges to connecting v and each of the spanning tree.

Then you will have a spanning tree of G, and there will be three cases.

**case 1**: degree v > k, in this case, the task is impossible

**case 2**: degree v = k, you have the answer.

**case 3**: degree v < k, then you just add unused edges of v. Each time you add an edge you will create a cycle, then you can just choose an edge which does not touch v and remove it.
You keep adding edges until you have your answer or all edges run out.
However, I cannot think of a fast way to query a cycle besides doing bfs/dfs.

**Update**: There is a faster way for **case 3** by Matt, after connecting v to k appropriate neighbors, use Kruskal's or Prim's algorithm to fill in the rest of the spanning tree, starting with the edges from v that you already have.

Comment: case 3:  after connecting `v` to k appropriate neighbors, use Kruskal's or Prim's algorithm to fill in the rest of the spanning tree, starting with the edges from `v` that you already have.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an algorithm that I am providing, but its pretty much brute force.

**Condition for such tree to exist**: if the `degree of v < k`, then such tree does not exist.

else follow the algorithm as:

Pick k vertices out of all the adjacent vertices of v,

```
1.mark all adjacent vertices of v as VISITED.

2.From each of those adjacent vertices , call DFS and the spanning tree grows.

3.After all DFS is complete,if all vertices of graph G are marked VISITED, then we
have our spanning tree, if a single vertex or more are left UNVISITED, then the 
4.pick another set of k vertices.
```

if `v` has `X` as degree and `X > k`, then step 4 has to be repeated `XCk(X choose k)` times in the worst case.

Comment: What happens if deg(v) > k?

Comment: Also, if a DFS from a neighbour of v takes in another neighbour of v, that neighbour will not then contribute to deg(v) in the final MST.

Answer (score 0):

We can think this way too:

1. For the given vertex v among all the neighbor v_i s.t. (v,v_i) in E(G) pick k edges with the smallest weights w(v,v_i), we need O(d*lg(d)) time where deg(v)=d >= k. Add these edges to the spanning tree edge set S. We have to add these edges to S anyway to ensure that the constraint holds.
2. Remove vertex v from the graph G along with all edges incident on v. Now run Prim/Kruskal on the graph G \ {v} starting with the edge set S, the algorithm itself will add edges ensuring the acyclic and minimum properties. This will run in O(m*lg(n)).

Assuming d small step 1 & 2 runs in O(m*lg(n)).

Comment: actually nobody said it should be a minimal spanning tree

Comment: oh  i assumed minimum, although minimum spanning tree is also a spanning tree, but the problem should even become easier.